# Read document from DocumentDB by ID using Node.js fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to read a single document from DocumentDB by using the document ID. The collection has four fields, `author` being the partition key.

```
{
  "id": string,
  "author": string,
  "title": string,
  "year": int
}
```

I have two functions for reading the records stored into DocumentDB. `queryCollectionByBookId` reads a single document by document id and `queryCollectionGetBooks` returns all the documents in the collection.

```
var dbutils = {
    queryCollectionByBookId: function(client, documentUrl) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            client.readDocument(documentUrl, function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(doc);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    queryCollectionGetBooks: function(client, collectionUrl) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            client.readDocuments(collectionUrl).toArray((err, results) => {
                if (err)
                    reject(err);
                else {
                    resolve(results);
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

`queryCollectionGetBooks` function works fine, but `queryCollectionByBookId` returns the error message below.

`{"Errors":["The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer components than defined in the the collection."]}`

Has anyone else seen this error message and found out how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an oversight in the documentation for the node.js client, but you have to add an `options.partitionKey` property to the optional second parameter in your `readDocument(link, options, callback)` call.

It's also an oversight in the docs but I think partitionKey needs to be an array with a single element (e.g. `{options: {partitionKey: ["myKey"]}}` [UPDATE: I'm told that it will now work with a single partition key value but I haven't confirmed it myself.]

Alternatively, you can set `options.enableCrossPartitionQuery` property to `true` but that is less efficient.

Comment: Thank you! Adding `options.partitionKey` property to `readDocument`call did the trick. 

The same trick works for the `enableCrossPartitionQuery` too. Enabling cross-partition query can be done setting `options.enableCrossPartitionQuery` property to `true`.

Comment: Good point but remember you take a larger and larger RU hit as you scale up using cross partition operations. It's probably fine for a single document but you want to avoid it for queries.