# Can't get simple CosmosDB query to work via Node.js - but works fine via Azure's Query Explorer

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm using CosmosDB (node.js via documentdb api) - partitioned on 'id' only.

A simple query (`SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.akunaCustomer = "xyz"`) works fine from Azure Query Explorer, but my node.js code gives the following error - running the identical query.

```
code: 400, BadRequest, Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this exception.
```

Here's my code:

```js
var documentClient = require("documentdb").DocumentClient;
var config = require("./config");

var client = new documentClient(config.endpoint, {"masterKey": config.primaryKey});

var databaseUrl = `dbs/${config.database.id}`;
var collectionUrl = `${databaseUrl}/colls/${config.collection.id}`;

client.queryDocuments(collectionUrl,
    'SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.akunaCustomer = "xyz"'
    ).toArray((err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
         else {
            for (var queryResult of results) {
                let resultString = JSON.stringify(queryResult);
                console.log(`Query: ${resultString}`);
            }
        }
    });
```

Clearly I'm missing something. :-(  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message is quite clear: because your query spans multiple partitions, you need to set `enableCrossPartitionQuery` option to `true`:

```js
client.queryDocuments(
    collectionUrl,
    'SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.akunaCustomer = "xyz"',
    { enableCrossPartitionQuery: true }
)
```

Comment: tx a million Mikhail. I searched high + low for the syntax to change the enableCrossPartitionQuery to true! Tx you again - i've just got a it working :-)