# Azure Function Javascript (NodeJS) CosmosDB query

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Very straightforward question. I have the following function inside my index.js file.

```js
const databaseId = config.database.id;
const collectionId = config.collection.id;
const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint: CosmosDBName, auth: { masterKey: CosmosDBKey } });
const query = `SELECT c.message.id FROM ${collectionId} c WHERE c.message.timestampFormatted > '${start}' AND c.message.timestampFormatted < '${end}'`;

queryCosmosDB(client, databaseId, collectionId, query)

async function queryCosmosDB(client, databaseId, collectionId, query, context) {
    const querySpec = {
        query: query,
        parameters: []
    };

    const { result: results } = await client.database(databaseId).container(collectionId).items.query(querySpec).toArray();

    for (var queryResult of results) {
        let resultString = JSON.stringify(queryResult);
        context.log(`\tQuery returned ${resultString}\n`);
    }
}
```

If I execute this function the response is the following error (I omitted some useless information)

```
ERROR: {"code":400,"body":"{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this exception. ...}
```

Now, I get the partition schema that CosmosDB uses but, in my case, what would be the best thing to do? Should I change somehow the query and if so how? If I have to insert some sort of cross partition query string how should I do that?

The only other question I found regarding this is [this SO's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125719/cant-get-simple-cosmosdb-query-to-work-via-node-js-but-works-fine-via-azures?rq=1) but I don't manage data as he does since I think the SDK has changed a lot from a year and a half ago. I'm currently using [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-get-started#Query) as baseline.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply enable cross partition queries using the NodeJS sdk by providing it as part of the options on the `query` function level.

```
async function queryCosmosDB(client, databaseId, collectionId, query, context) {
    const querySpec = {
        query: query,
        parameters: []
    };

    const options = {
        enableCrossPartitionQuery: true
      };

    const { result: results } = await client.database(databaseId).container(collectionId).items.query(querySpec, options).toArray();

    for (var queryResult of results) {
        let resultString = JSON.stringify(queryResult);
        context.log(`\tQuery returned ${resultString}\n`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, after having posted the question I searched the SDK documentation to find this property and found it exactly when you answered. Anyway thanks a lot very helpful!