# Cosmos DB - Delete Document with Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871925/cosmos-db-deleting-a-document) I had learnt that I cannot delete a Cosmos DB document using SQL.

Using Python, I believe I need the `DeleteDocument()` method. This is how I'm getting the document ID's that are required (I believe) to then call the `DeleteDocument()` method.

```
# set up the client
client = document_client.DocumentClient()

# use a SQL based query to get a bunch of documents
query = { 'query': 'SELECT * FROM server s' }
result_iterable = client.QueryDocuments('dbs/DB/colls/coll', query, options)

results = list(result_iterable);

for x in range(0, len (results)):
    docID = results[x]['id']
```

Now, at this stage I want to call `DeleteDocument()`.
The inputs into which are `document_link` and `options`.

I can define `document_link` as something like

```
document_link = 'dbs/DB/colls/coll/docs/'+docID
```

And successfully call `ReadAttachments()` for example, which has the same inputs as `DeleteDocument()`.

When I do however, I get an error...

```
The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer
components than defined in the the collection
```

...and now I'm totally lost

**UPDATE**

Following on from Jay's help, I believe I'm missing the `partitonKey` element in the options.

In this example, I've created a testing database, it looks like this
[image: Screen grab from my Azure account]

So I think my partition key is `/testPART`

When I include the `partitionKey` in the options however, no results are returned, (and so `print len(results)` outputs 0).

Removing `partitionKey` means that results are returned, but the delete attempt fails as before.

```
# Query them in SQL
query = { 'query': 'SELECT * FROM c' }

options = {}
options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
options['maxItemCount'] = 2
options['partitionKey'] = '/testPART'
result_iterable = client.QueryDocuments('dbs/testDB/colls/testCOLL', query, options)
results = list(result_iterable)

# should be > 0
print len(results)

for x in range(0, len (results)):
    docID = results[x]['id']
    print docID
    client.DeleteDocument('dbs/testDB/colls/testCOLL/docs/'+docID, options=options)
    print 'deleted', docID
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your description, I tried to use [pydocument module](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-documentdb-python-getting-started/blob/master/DocumentDBGetStarted.py) to delete document in my `azure document db` and it works for me.

Here is my code:

```
import pydocumentdb;
import pydocumentdb.document_client as document_client

config = {
    'ENDPOINT': 'Your url',
    'MASTERKEY': 'Your master key',
    'DOCUMENTDB_DATABASE': 'familydb',
    'DOCUMENTDB_COLLECTION': 'familycoll'
};

# Initialize the Python DocumentDB client
client = document_client.DocumentClient(config['ENDPOINT'], {'masterKey': config['MASTERKEY']})

# use a SQL based query to get a bunch of documents
query = { 'query': 'SELECT * FROM server s' }

options = {}
options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
options['maxItemCount'] = 2

result_iterable = client.QueryDocuments('dbs/familydb/colls/familycoll', query, options)

results = list(result_iterable);

print(results)

client.DeleteDocument('dbs/familydb/colls/familycoll/docs/id1',options)

print 'delete success'
```

***Console Result:***

```
[{u'_self': u'dbs/hitPAA==/colls/hitPAL3OLgA=/docs/hitPAL3OLgABAAAAAAAAAA==/', u'myJsonArray': [{u'subId': u'sub1', u'val': u'value1'}, {u'subId': u'sub2', u'val': u'value2'}], u'_ts': 1507687788, u'_rid': u'hitPAL3OLgABAAAAAAAAAA==', u'_attachments': u'attachments/', u'_etag': u'"00002100-0000-0000-0000-59dd7d6c0000"', u'id': u'id1'}, {u'_self': u'dbs/hitPAA==/colls/hitPAL3OLgA=/docs/hitPAL3OLgACAAAAAAAAAA==/', u'myJsonArray': [{u'subId': u'sub3', u'val': u'value3'}, {u'subId': u'sub4', u'val': u'value4'}], u'_ts': 1507687809, u'_rid': u'hitPAL3OLgACAAAAAAAAAA==', u'_attachments': u'attachments/', u'_etag': u'"00002200-0000-0000-0000-59dd7d810000"', u'id': u'id2'}]
delete success
```

Please notice that you need to set the `enableCrossPartitionQuery` property to **True** in `options` if your documents are `cross-partitioned`.

> Must be set to true for any query that requires to be executed across
>   more than one partition. This is an explicit flag to enable you to
>   make conscious performance tradeoffs during development time.

You could find above description from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query-metrics).

---

Update Answer:

I think you misunderstand the meaning of `partitionkey` property in the `options[]`.

For example , my container is created like this:

[image]

My documents as below :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "jay"
}

{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "jay2"
}
```

My `partitionkey` is **'name'**, so here I have two paritions : **'jay'** and **'jay1'**.

So, here you should set the `partitionkey` property to 'jay' or 'jay2',not 'name'.

Please modify your code as below:

```
 options = {}
    options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
    options['maxItemCount'] = 2
    options['partitionKey'] = 'jay' (please change here in your code)

    result_iterable = client.QueryDocuments('dbs/db/colls/testcoll', query, options)
    results = list(result_iterable);

    print(results)
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Jay, unfortunately that doesn't work for me - passing in those options with `enableCrossPartitionQuery` as `True` or `False` - error is in the same as in the question

Comment: @BenMayo It's werid. The above code works well for me.If you try it completely,would you please update  general structure of your database to let me help you solve this issue?  In,addition, you could refer to this case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999586/read-document-from-documentdb-by-id-using-node-js-fails/43002819#43002819

Comment: @BenMayo Any concern,please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Using the *azure.cosmos* library:

install and import azure cosmos package:

```
from azure.cosmos import exceptions, CosmosClient, PartitionKey
```

define delete items function - in this case using the partition key in query:

```
def deleteItems(deviceid):
    client = CosmosClient(config.cosmos.endpoint, config.cosmos.primarykey)

    # Create a database if not exists
    database = client.create_database_if_not_exists(id=azure-cosmos-db-name)

    # Create a container
    # Using a good partition key improves the performance of database operations.
    container = database.create_container_if_not_exists(id=container-name, partition_key=PartitionKey(path='/your-pattition-path'), offer_throughput=400)

    #fetch items
    query = f"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.device.deviceid IN ('{deviceid}')"
    items = list(container.query_items(query=query, enable_cross_partition_query=False))
    for item in items:
        container.delete_item(item, 'partition-key')
```

usage:

```
deviceid=10
deleteItems(items)
```

github full example here: https://github.com/eladtpro/python-iothub-cosmos