# Cosmos DB - Problems in Delete all data with Python

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

I am working with Cosmos db from azure and the SQL API using python.

I have uploaded some data into cosmos db, but now I want to delete it.

I have seen in this question how to do it: [Cosmos DB - Delete Document with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878227/cosmos-db-delete-document-with-python)

But for me is not working, This is my code:

```
config = {
    'ENDPOINT': "ENDPOINT",
    'MASTERKEY': 'key',
    'DOCUMENTDB_DATABASE': 'database',
    'DOCUMENTDB_COLLECTION': 'collection'
};

# Initialize the Python DocumentDB client
client = document_client.DocumentClient(config['ENDPOINT'], {'masterKey': config['MASTERKEY']})

# use a SQL based query to get a bunch of documents
query = { 'query': 'SELECT * FROM c' }

options = {}
options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
options['maxItemCount'] = -1
options['partitionKey'] = '2017'

result_iterable = client.QueryDocuments('dbs/database/colls/collection', query, options)

results = list(result_iterable);

print(results)

#client.DeleteDocument('dbs/ToDoList/colls/nc4data/docs/'+result_iterableID,options)
for x in range(0, len (results)):
    docID = results[x]['id']
    print (docID)
    client.DeleteDocument('dbs/database/colls/collection/docs/'+docID, options=options)
    print ('deleted', docID)
#print ('delete success')
```

My partition key are years, from 2016 to 2019. What I have tried is to asing partition key in options as one of the years, as the answer I linked above:

```
options['partitionKey'] = '2017'
```

Also I have tried to do this:

```
options['partitionKey'] = 2017 (year is string, but I was trying)
options['partitionKey'] = 'year'
options['partitionKey'] = '/year'
```

When I insert this 'partitionKey' in my options dictionary I am obtaining an empy list in results.

Also I have tryied without this 'partitionKey', then I get all data, but I get this error:

{\"Errors\":[\"The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer components than defined in the the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the code in my previous thread: [Cosmos DB - Delete Document with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878227/cosmos-db-delete-document-with-python) and it works fine.

```
import pydocumentdb;
import pydocumentdb.document_client as document_client

config = {
    'ENDPOINT': 'Your url',
    'MASTERKEY': 'Your master key',
    'DOCUMENTDB_DATABASE': 'familydb',
    'DOCUMENTDB_COLLECTION': 'familycoll'
};

# Initialize the Python DocumentDB client
client = document_client.DocumentClient(config['ENDPOINT'], {'masterKey': config['MASTERKEY']})

# use a SQL based query to get a bunch of documents
query = { 'query': 'SELECT * FROM server s' }

options = {}
options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
options['maxItemCount'] = 2

result_iterable = client.QueryDocuments('dbs/familydb/colls/familycoll', query, options)

results = list(result_iterable);

print(results)

client.DeleteDocument('dbs/familydb/colls/familycoll/docs/id1',options)

print 'delete success'
```

I searched exact issue from github and i found that it is caused by the sdk version. You could upgrade your package version or monitor the https request by Fiddler Tool.Please refer to below threads:

1.https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ios/issues/108

2.https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-android/issues/75

3.https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ios/pull/114